# Can't display more than one search result in jtable

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable

I've been trying to get my search results to appear in a jtable. Now I've been able to display results for codes in the database which have only one variant. But some of the codes in the database have more than one variant. For instance 034\OT\01 or 034\CT\01 or 034\OT\04. Now if you put in the search 034 the jtable doesn't display anything. It does display a code in the database and all the details if there's only one line for instance 400.

I've added my search code below. Hope you can help :).

```
try {
String sql = "SELECT * FROM nameOfDatabase WHERE code LIKE ?";

pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, txt_search.getText());

rs=pst.executeQuery();
table_details.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

} catch (Exception e) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: It was only after reading this carefully, several times, that I realized I have no idea what you are talking about.  DYM that the search query for the DB is not pulling the records you expected?  In that case, this has little if anything to do with `JTable`.

Comment: Looks like you are not adding wildcards to your SQL-query.

Comment: Seems to be the wildcards thank you. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you again.

Comment: Many `RowSorter` answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A203657+%5Bjtable%5D+RowSorter).